# issue Letter Grades on python

Tags: python, sorting

Hi all I'm having an issue with my python code.

Im new to python im study at tafe and this is one of my task for introduction to python

The task is to make a simple code that grades the letters from the total and in oreder for example HD, D, C, P, F here the code I made so far :

```
#Blank variable to store user input and GPA
totals = set()
letters = set()

#Get and store user input
print ("Please enter the grade for each student, or press q to quit")
while(True):
    user_input = input("> ")
    if(user_input.lower() == "q"):
        break
    totals.add(user_input)

#Caclulate letter grade for each user response
for total in totals:
    if total <= "59":
        letters.add("F")
    elif total <= "69":
        letters.add("P")
    elif total <= "79":
        letters.add("C")
    elif total <= "89":
        letters.add("D")
    else:
        letters.add("HD")


letters = ['HD', 'D', 'C', 'P', 'F']

#Print GPA results.
print("The GPA for your students is: {}".format(letters))
```

The issue is I'm having is I am trying to duplicate the grades and have them in order for for example if I input 90, 80 , 88 , 75 it should print out like this HD, D, D, C but when I do it ,it only does this HD, D, C

I tried everything but nothing work I'll look everywhere online but no luck

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: You're using a set, which by definition does not accept duplicates. Use a list with `.append()` instead of `.add()` rather than a set.

Comment: i try it did not work

Comment: did you remove the `letters = ['HD' ... 'F']` near the end? That will overwrite the array with the preset values.

Comment: i did that just now it giving me this 8, in <module>
    totals.append(user_input)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: are you sure you want to compare `str` and not `int` (e.g in `if total <= "59":`)?

Comment: no meant to be like that that the teacher task me and calss as part of introduction to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `sets` to `list` and `add()` to `append()`, also remove the `letters = ['HD', 'D', 'C', 'P', 'F']` at the bottom that is overriding the results.

```
#Blank variable to store user input and GPA
totals = list()
letters = list()


print ("Please enter the grade for each student, or press q to quit")
while(True):
    user_input = input("> ")
    if(user_input.lower() == "q"):
        break
    totals.append(user_input)

#Caclulate letter grade for each user response
for total in totals:
    if total <= '59':
        letters.append("F")
    elif total <= '69':
        letters.append("P")
    elif total <= '79':
        letters.append("C")
    elif total <= '89':
        letters.append("D")
    else:
        letters.append("HD")


#Print GPA results.
print("The GPA for your students is: {}".format(letters))
```

As you are doing string comparisons, you should be careful to consider what if the entry is not a number that also is not `q`. I could enter a grade of `"Apples"` and it would give a grade of `HD`. You can also consider doing it as int comparisons, but you would also need to do checks before converting the string to int.

Comment: ok that work but i need to have the grads in order im new to this so im soory about that  code is ment to be simple  that the teacher task me and calss as part of introduction to python so soory about that

Comment: in what order? ascending or descending? by alphabetical order or numerical equivalent?

Comment: kind of like ascending  so like HD, D, C, P, F

Comment: That's descending in order of their numerical equivalents. Simplest way to do it is sort the `totals` before you convert them to letters, so add `totals.sort(reverse=True)` before the for loop.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH it all goos now i am sorry for taking up your time im still new this my subject is introduction to python at tafe so still go alot to learn thank yuo again